# Copy a webpage's text to a single cell in Excel with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to pull an entire webpage (a news story) into a single cell. The problem is, when Excel outputs the website, every new line in the source text is placed in a new row. I'd like to know how to output it into one cell.

I have tried many methods, but they don't work because my version of Excel doesn't come with certain libraries? (My knowledge of computer science is limited.) I'm using a 2015 version of Excel on OS X. That's what I'm working with. The eventual goal of this whole project is for Excel to search a whole list of websites (a column of URLs) for a single term (stored in M5 right now), and output YES or NO which of the sites contain that term. For now, I'm trying it out on a single URL stored in E12.

```
Sub SearchSite()
strsearch = Range("M5")
theurl = Range("E12")

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & theurl, Destination:=Range("P1"))
.Name = "NewsQuery"
.AdjustColumnWidth = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
End With

Debug.Print "DONE"

End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious why you want it all in a single cell - is it so you can search for the word in `M5`?  Just asking, because if you're trying to do anything with the data, having it all in a single cell will make things a bit more complicated as opposed to having it split over rows.  Perhaps you could put all the websites in different columns? Or different sheets?  If you do want a single cell, why not add a subroutine that just takes all the rows, and adds that string into your first cell?

Comment: I'm starting to realize I could get the job done with all the text in separate rows. I thought it would be unmanageable if I had to repeat this process for many websites, but maybe it wouldn't.

Comment: Part of the problem with many rows is that I'd have to have Excel search through an arbitrarily high number of rows, because each site's text will fill an unpredictable number of rows. Aha, Rows.Count may hold the answer...

Comment: did my answer help any? Edit: actually I just realized you'll probably run into an issue with a single cell because excel has a max character limit per cell...

Comment: Yes it did! The reason why I thought I wanted the whole text in one cell was because I didn't want to search for text for an arbitrarily high number of rows, like hundreds of rows. But Rows.Count (with certain manipulations) solves this problem.

Comment: Not sure if the WebService function would work on Mac https://blogs.office.com/2013/03/21/use-webservice-functions-to-automatically-update-excel-2013-spreadsheets-with-online-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, perahps it's better to keep them all in separate rows.  However, if you do need them to be in one cell only, you can use a second Sub to do so:

```
Sub combineCellsIntoOne(dest As Range)
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, dest.Column).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long
For i = dest.Row + 1 To lastRow
    dest.Value = dest.Value & " " & Cells(i, dest.Column).Value
    Cells(i, dest.Column).ClearContents
Next i

End Sub
```

You can put `combineCellsIntoOne Range("P1")` after the `End With` in your original one.  That should work (note to change the destination range if/as necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing. The URLs are stored in Column E.

```
Public strsearch As String

Sub SearchSite()
    For j = Selection.Row To Selection.Row + Selection.Rows.count - 1

' Get the URL
        theurl = Range("E" & j)
        If theurl = "" Then GoTo NextRow

' Fill the Query Table
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & theurl, Destination:=Range("P1"))
        .Name = "NewsQuery"
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = False
    End With


' Search the Query Table for the Search Term
    strsearch = Range("M5")
    bottomrow = Range("P" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To bottomrow
        If InStr(Range("P" & i), strsearch) <> 0 Then
            Range("K" & j) = "YES"
            Exit For
        End If
        Range("K" & j) = "NO"
    Next i

    NextRow:
Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
'Import Everything From a Web Page:

Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com" ' should work for any URL
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

            Range("A1").Value = .document.body.innertext

            .Quit
        End With

End Sub
```