# Trying to find an instance of one word on a webpage, but my attempt to scrape the data fails at the first hurdle

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to create a function that takes an MRN e.g. 21GB000246123A08C7 and puts it into this website:

https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/tra/transit_home.jsp?Lang=en&Expand=true&MRN=21GB000246123A08C7

Then my function will scrape the text from the sight, at which point I can check for the word "control" and return true or false.

I have tried multiple ways of doing this and eventually I have realised that the table doesn't seem to even appear when scraping *all* of the page as plain text:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/tra/transit_home.jsp?Lang=en&Expand=true&MRN=21GB000246123A08C7" ' should work for any URL
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

            Range("A1").Value = .document.body.innertext

            .Quit
        End With

End Sub
```

Disclaimer I found this code here: [Copy a webpage's text to a single cell in Excel with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726414/copy-a-webpages-text-to-a-single-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Why does the link load properly when I open it in Internet explorer, but when I try to scrape it I only receive "No MRN entered" in place of the table of information I need.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Leave a long enough load time for page to have updated Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110592/6241235 though please use a proper page load wait first of `While .busy Or .readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Wend` before the timed loop.

Comment: ^^ that, but use `Do...Loop` instead of the obsolete `While...Wend` construct ;-)